# Does not retrieve XML file and indicates pages from news

Tags: c#, xml

It's like news should be listed in my xml file. Right now there is nothing at all, but it must be such that it just indicates the news as soon as it has been created.

As it is right now, nothing comes forth

There is no error message about it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset>
  <new>
    <url>
      <Loc></Loc>
      <lastmod></lastmod>
      <changefreq></changefreq>
    </url>
  </new>
</urlset>
```

Update XML HERE:

```
public static void ListXML()
    {
        using (var DB = new DBEntitiesDatabase())
        {
            var url = @"C:\Users\HelloWorld\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Test\Website";
            var urlxml = url + "/sitemap.xml";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(urlxml);
            var newlist = DB.New.OrderBy(i => i.NewId).ToList();
            foreach (var item in newlist)
            {
                new XElement("new",
                    new XElement("url",
                      new XElement("Loc", url + "/nyhed/" + item.url + "/" + item.NewId),
                      new XElement("lastmod", item.opretDato),
                      new XElement("changefreq", "daily")));
            }

            doc.Save(urlxml);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe if you add the new elements to the document it may work... :D

Comment: What elements do you think about? @Gusman

Comment: Look your loop, you are creating the elements but not adding them to the doc.

Comment: Thanks @Gusman for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are generating  xml tag, but not appending it to the xml document.

Solution: try to append your tag to document like this:

```
// in foreach loop
var newTag = new XElement("new"... /*etc like you generating it*/);
// assuming you already have root xml tag in your file
doc.Root.Add(newTag);
```

(I don't remember exact API of XDocument tree manipulation, but hope you got the idea)

Comment: Okay Thanks but where come Newtag from?

Comment: u mean `var newtag = new XElement("new".`

Comment: Oh, I forgot that `new` is actually reserved word; for sure it should be `newTag` or smth like this. Glad to hear you have it works :)